# What are empty-body methods used for in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, methods

Currently reading a [Ruby style guide](https://rubystyle.guide/#no-single-line-methods) and I came across an example:

```
def no_op; end
```

What is the purpose of empty body methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of reasons you might create an empty method:

- Stub a method that you will fill in later.
- Stub a method that a descendant class will override.
- Ensure a class or object will [#respond_to?](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F) a method without necessarily doing anything other than returning nil.
- Undefine an inherited method's behavior while still allowing it to #respond_to? the message, as opposed to using `undef foo` on public methods and surprising callers.

There are possibly other reasons, too, but those are the ones that leapt to mind. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: However, also from the Ruby style guide (the source of the question): "Prefer duck-typing over inheritance." Meaning: avoid using empty methods that a descendant class will override. https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#duck-typing

Answer (score 1):

There may be several reasons.

One case is when a class is expected to implement a specific interface (virtually speaking, given that in Ruby there are no interfaces), but in that specific class that method would not make sense. In this case, the method is left for consistency.

```
class Foo
  def say
    "foo"
  end
end

class Bar
  def say
    "bar"
  end
end

class Null
  def say
  end
end
```

In other cases, it is left as a temporary placeholder or reminder.

There are also cases where the method is left blank on purpose, as a hook for developers using that library. The method it is called somewhere at runtime, and developers using that library can override the blank method in order to execute some custom callback. This approach was used in the past by some Rails libraries.